# How to deploy GKE specific version using ansible

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ansible, google-kubernetes-engine

I was trying to use ansible to deploy the GKE cluster. But when I use initialClusterVersion with ansible `gcp_container_cluster`, the error output like this.

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported
> parameters for (gcp_container_cluster) module: initialClusterVersion
> Supported parameters include: addons_config, auth_kind,
> cluster_ipv4_cidr, default_max_pods_constraint, description,
> enable_tpu, env_type, initial_node_count, ip_allocation_policy,
> kubectl_context, kubectl_path, legacy_abac, location, locations,
> logging_service, master_auth, monitoring_service, name, network,
> network_policy, node_config, private_cluster_config, project,
> resource_labels, scopes, service_account_contents,
> service_account_email, service_account_file, state, subnetwork,
> tpu_ipv4_cidr_block"}

Comment: You should provide a [mre] to reproduce your issue, otherwise it would be plain guessing. Your version of Ansible might also help.

Answer (score 0):

`initialClusterVersion` is a [return value](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/google/cloud/gcp_container_cluster_module.html#return-initialClusterVersion), not a parameter.

You can use the `initial_cluster_version` [parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/google/cloud/gcp_container_cluster_module.html#parameter-initial_cluster_version) if using Ansible versions 2.10 or 3.

Looking at your error message listing the supported parameters, I assume you are using an older version, and therefore will need to upgrade if you need to use the `initial_cluster_version` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I am using Ansible 2.9.
Anyway, I managed to get the correct version with gcp_container_node_pool.
As a workaround, I use the node pool GKE version.

```
- gcp_container_node_pool 
    version: 1.18.16-gke.302
```